# Json Manipulation if json key having more than one fields

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a json like this:

```json
[
    {
        "objectid":"61b1",
        "name":["abc","xyz"],
        "date":["2021-08-20","2021-09-20"]
    }
]
```

I want to manipulate the json to create a simple one as below:

```json
[
    {
        "objectid":"61b1",
        "name":"abc",
        "date":"2021-08-20"
    },
    {
        "objectid":"61b1",
        "name":"xyz",
        "date":"2021-09-20"
    }
]
```

Please help if anyone has done this earlier. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you got stuck? Please see [ask] and [tour].

Answer (score 0):

You can use **reduce** to split date and name for each element and push the splite value to the accumulated result as follow:

```
var input = [
    {
        "objectid":"61b1",
        "name":["abc","xyz"],
        "date":["2021-08-20","2021-09-20"]
    }
];


var output = input.reduce(function(acc, curr){
    //foreach element we try to slipt it 
    // if we have more than one element in date or name 

    if(curr.name.length > 0 && curr.date.length > 0){
        //we make sur that we the same length of date et name        
        var length = Math.min(curr.name.length, curr.date.length);
        for(var i = 0; i < length; i ++){
           var name = curr.name[i];
           var date = curr.date[i];
          
           acc.push({
               "objectid": curr.objectid,
               "name": name,
               "date": date 
           });
        }

    }else{
        acc.push(curr);
    }
    return acc;
},[])

output;
```